# Wordpress programmatically create a published post and attach ACF field values

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a post on the fly and make it published. This was working but after update of wordpress and plugins the code no longer works. the code also has a uid which is saved to an ACF field. In a functions file I have a function which checks if there is a custom post type with the uid, if it exists we load the post, if not we create the post. Heres my code:

```
    $getPosts = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'stock',
        'meta_key' => 'uid',
        'meta_value' => '123'
    ));

    if ($getPosts) {
        $post = $getPosts[0];
    } else {
        // create a new published post for this data

        $newPost = array(
            'post_title'   => 'Test 1',
            'post_name'    => 'test-1',
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_type'    => 'stock',
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'post_author'  => 1
        );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($newPost);
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        update_field('uid', '123', $post->ID);

    }
```

I'm using php8.1 and wordpress 5.9.2

To summarise the result is not published (it is created as a draft), if i run the code again it doesn't find the stock post with the uid and then creates a new draft one etc.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working fine to add a post in `stock` post type.
I think its missing [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) `uid` field.
Check the custom field is availble or not in the system.
[Learn more](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-posts/) how to create new field in ACF.

I have another solution that perform the same stuff:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'stock',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'uid',
            'value'   => '123',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

$getPosts = new WP_Query($args);

if($getPosts->found_posts){
    $post = $getPosts->posts[0];
}else{
    $args = array(
        'post_title'   => 'Test 1',
        'post_name'    => 'test-1',
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_type'    => 'stock',
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_author'  => 1
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($newPost);
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    update_field('uid', '123', $post->ID);
}
```

Above code use [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) to get the post data.